# Implementing Different Font Styles in a Single FormView C#

Tags: c#, css, fonts, eval, formview

I'm trying to add different font styles and sizes to one of the fields below. I'm using a FormView and am extracting the data using <%Eval("fieldname")%>. For this question I'm looking at the 'Comments' Eval field.

The output for this field will look like this:

"- this is a comment.
Commented by John Doe 27/09/2016 16:58

-another comment.
Commented by John Doe 27/09/2016 16:59"

Now my question is how to change the font styles of both comment value (- this is a comment.) and the user who commented (Commented by John...).

Basically, I want the comment to standout than the commented by section.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```html
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="fvReport" DataKeyNames="ReportId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" BorderStyle="None">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="body2">
                            <h4><%# Eval("Report_Type") %> Report ID No. <%# Eval("ReportId") %></h4>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5">Shift Details</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="border: solid .5px;">
                                    <td>Staff Name:</td>
                                    <td style="width: 285px">
                                        <%# Eval("StaffName") %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 19%">Shift Type: 
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%# Eval("ShiftName") %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right;">Shift Date:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ShiftDate")).ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="4">Report</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <%# Eval("Report") %>                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="4">Comments</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <%# Eval("Comments") %>">                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that comments is just a record(not like records set) and if you want to use same font for all comments

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style>
     <span style="font-size:12px;....">
       <%# Eval("Comments")
            .ToString()
            .Substring(
              0, 
              Eval("Comments")
                .ToString()
                .IndexOf(" Commented by")) %>">                    
      </span>
      <span style="font-size:8px;....">
       <%# Eval("Comments")
            .ToString()
            .Substring(
              Eval("Comments")
                .ToString()
                .IndexOf(" Commented by")) %>">                    
      </span>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hi Dakmaz! Thank you for your reply. Yes it is just a record from a table. a sample record will look like this: - this is a test<br/>Commented by John Doe 28/09/2016 08:55<br/><br/>-another test comment<br/>Commented by Bob Shanks 28/09/2016 09:27. I tried the script you've given and it does change the font for the first comment by anything after the first 'Commented by' string gets set to a font size of 8. These comments are considered to be record sets separated by a breakline. Any other workaround about this?